# How i can do wildcard subdomain support for multistore opencart 2x?

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, wildcard-subdomain

I have a question, opencart supports only specific domain names like `site.com`. What do I have to do to support domains like `*.site.com` ?

**Main idea:**

Product SEO url will replace subdomain. For example, product have SEO name `iphone6`, so url will be `iphone6.site.com`, how can I do this? Do I need `.htaccess` mod? Or what? Or in `config.php` write what domain `http://www.*.site.com/`? Thanks for you answers!

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have 4 sites,

- site1.com
- site2.com
- site3.com
- site4.com witch is the only site that needs to support `*.site4.com`

How can I do this for multistore opencart 2x?

P.S: in Cpanel (domain thread) I already added such domain *.site.com support, I only need opencart to support this.

I will be glad to any advice :)